# Has X-Men ever offered an in-universe explanation for how the "impossible" arises from a biological explanation?

Tags: marvel, x-men, history-of, physics

First, let me say, I know people are going to say "It's just a comic/movie franchise, you have to suspend disbelief".   Please bear with me.

X-Men is a little different than other franchises.

We have the concepts of [Homo superior/ homo mutandis / mutantur / homo sapiens supreme](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Homo_superior) and the [X-Gene / mutant gene / X-Factor chromosome / X-Factor / etc](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/X-Gene).   And these are very central to the plotlines.

In other words, there is the attempt to explain the multitude of powers arising through a biological explanation.   Maybe it's just me, but that is qualitatively different than a lot of other origin stories, like 'he's an alien' or 'he can do magic'.   (Yes, I realize people will give examples of other superheroes/villains where a biological explanation is attempted, but this question is about X-Men, and it's probably different because in X-Men it is literally in the DNA.)

But here we have all kinds of powers (turning to diamond, telekenesis, opening portals to other dimensions, teleportation, controlling weather, etc.) that clearly can't have a biological basis (at least in our universe).

So, what I'm probably not explaining very well, is that the idea of the impossible arising from an impossible explanation isn't the same as the impossible arising from a supposed plausible explanation (genes).  So it's only a partial explanation.   Is there then a part of the explanation that tries to close the gap?

## Is there an explanation offered in-universe for how the X-Gene allows homo superior to access physics that is impossible in *our* universe ?

Comment: Considering the general Marvel universe with all sorts of powers and magic, I'm really not certain what there is to explain. A lot of it comes down to some degree of psychic abilities and alternate dimensions (dimensions actually come up a number of times from the Summers brothers sourcing their blasts there or Nightcrawler's teleportation involving popping in and out of a brimstone dimension). But outside of that, they simply live in a world where a lot of people can do things they can't do in our world. Genetics to tap into that doesn't seem all that odd.

Comment: Or are you commenting specifically on the Fox depiction, which lacks a lot of the other weirdness?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots:  Any depiction is fine.   You don't see the oddity of saying it comes from a gene, which is ultimately just a sequence of base pairs that make a protein.   It is the partial explanation I'm asking about.   It is really partial or is there more to the explanation?

Comment: I don't see the oddity of it, any more than there's oddity in a group of genes that allows us to see light within (only) a specified range of wavelengths.

Comment: @MattGutting:   I literally don't understand this point.   It's completely within the realm of possibility for altered genes to produce new receptors in your retina that can react to different wavelengths of light.   There's is currently to means for any kind of genetics to let you teleport.   It's just not he same level of plausibility.

Comment: In our universe. But in the X-men universe?

Comment: @ThePopMachine. There's also currently no science that allows human beings to teleport.  What makes you think that in a universe where teleportation is possible, it's not possible as an evolutionary advantage?

Comment: @Paul, entirely possible.  The question is whether they ever did offer any explanation.  The answer could be, "No, it's just how that universe is."  That's an answer too.

Comment: They're not just any genes, they're plot device genes. I really think the "it's just comics" explanation is what's going on here. I'm sure there are multiple layers of retcons about how the powers actually work, but in the end, the explanations are just excuses for having superheroes. Hopefully someone will post an answer explaining some of these explanations.

Comment: Some related posts: [Do mutants who have mind powers have their power as a part of their atomic structure the same way mutants with physical powers, or not?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/142561), [Is the mutant gene dominant or recessive?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/92919), [Are the mutations in the Marvel Universe that were created by Celestials only able to be created by Celestial technology?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/109634), [What is the mutagen responsible for mutation in the Marvel Universe?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/71313)

Comment: [The X-FACTOR gene in Ultimate X-men](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/36822), [Why do mutants get their specific powers?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/95568), [Is there a set limit on mutant abilities, where they're deemed too unrealistic?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/17404), [Why does Magneto not exhaust himself? Where does he get his energy source?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/40738)

Comment: Personally, I don't see any qualitative difference between "he's a mutant" and "he's an alien" or for that matter "he was exposed to gamma rays" or "he was injected with a serum" or "he was bitten by a radioactive spider".  All equally fake-scientific as far as i can see.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: you don't see a difference between "he can do alien things because he's an alien", "he can do magic because magic exists", and "he can teleport because he has a few As, Cs, Gs, and Ts in a different place" ?  So it's not just "he's a mutant". The disparity is that they claimed specific thing that "being a mutant" is.Yes, as I said in the original post, this argument could be made about some others (like your examples), but this question is about X-Men. You can ask about if anyone ever tried to explain how gamma radiation leads to Hulk's powers, but that is a different question.

Comment: It's a valid question, I guess, I just don't agree with the assertion that there is any qualitative difference between this and most other superhero origin stories.  "Being an alien" seems a particularly pertinent example, since that's *also* a matter of having different As, Cs, Gs, and Ts, or equivalent thereof.

Comment: ... thinking out loud: it seems to me there's always going to be a hierarchy of explanations, so you can say "they're mutants" and then follow up with "they've got this specific unusual gene" or you can say "he's an alien" and then follow up with "his native planet has a different type of sun", but given that what you're trying to explain is inherently unrealistic, no matter how deep you go you still wind up relying on suspension of disbelief.

Comment: ... of course it is still a meaningful question to ask "canon provides Superficially Plausible But Ultimately Meaningless explanation A, and follow-up SPBUM explanation B, is there yet another follow-up SPBUM explanation C" but I think the resistance to your question may be because of the implication that there *should* be a C to "close the gap" as you put it.  You're *never* going to close the gap.  I think the only reason to have a C, or even a B, is if they advance the plot.

Comment: @HarryJohnston, yeah, understood.   I am drawing a line, but only because (1) in this is case it is so central to the material, and (2) there is offered a supposed explanation that is meaningful in our world and (3) that explanation in our world is still so far from the resulting powers.    I don't have a problem with the supposed resistance; in fact I even pointed it out myself in the original question. But really, I wouldn't even consider the resistance so strong since there seems to be reasonable agreement (+7,-0 at this moment) that the question is understandable and interesting.

Comment: “But here we have all kinds of powers (turning to diamond, telekenesis, opening portals to other dimensions, teleportation, controlling weather, etc.) that clearly can't have a biological basis” — clearly! Genes are biology! Weather is physics! In high school, they’re taught in *entirely different classrooms!*

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there has ever been an explicit in-universe explanation. There have been a few stories that have hinted that humans have an extranormal evolutionary capability (Rick Jones' powers during the Kree-Skrull War (and AVENGERS FOREVER); X-MEN ANNUAL 11 (which basically just said humans didn't veer down a dead-end path like others)).

There are other stories that one can turn that same direction. I have long had a theory as to how Richard Ryder regained his Nova abilities after having lost them (prior to the original NEW WARRIORS series), involving the blast of energy that shot out of his eyes (in NOVA vol 1 #1, circa 1976); namely, that the energy required to give most races the Nova powers was more than was needed for humans; and that, after losing the powers, he absorbed the "extra" energy he had originally shed, to regain them. However, that's my theory, nothing explicitly (or even implicitly, to be honest) stated.

Of course, it's not entirely fair to pick on the X-Men franchise here. Given the number of characters receiving their powers from an overexposure of some sort to radiation (Fantastic Four, Hulk, Spider-Man), as opposed to gain the power to get very sick, lose their hair, and die. In fact, to bring it back to the X-Men, it's strongly implied that Hank McCoy's mutation was due to his parents' work in a nuclear plant (or something of the sort).

I'll also note WHAT IF (vol 1) #6, where we have a Fantastic Four given a different set of abilities (Reed becomes a floating brain, Johnny an android-like being, Sue get stretching abilities, and Ben sprouts insect/dragon wings). Here, the Watcher explains how the character's powers matched their personalities in some way (both for the original team, and for this variant). This, of course, leans in the direction of the WILD CARDS style explanation another respondent posted. This may be the closest to an in-universe explanation I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

It's a different 'verse (George R. R. Martin's [*Wildcards*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wild_Cards) 'verse) but here's an excerpt from an appendix in the first book that give some kind of explanation.

Book 1, [*Wild Cards,*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003P8OZ0U) Appendix II, *"Excerpts from the Minutes of the American Metabiological Society Conference on Metahuman Abilities":*

> We now have a better idea of just what wild card did to its victims. In so-called ace cases, the virus appears to have acted first by enhancing innate psychic ability, which gave direction to the overall progress of the gene-code rewrite. This explains the high degrees of correspondence between the personalities and proclivities of known aces and their metahuman abilities—why, for example, devoted pilots such as Black Eagle acquired powers including that of flight, why the obsessed “avenger of the night” Black Shadow has such control over darkness, why the reclusive Aquarius presents a half-human, half-delfin appearance and can in fact transform himself into a sort of super-Tursiops. A microscale telekinesis appears to be one of the mechanisms by which wild card effects its changes, enabling the subject subconsciously to choose, or at least influence, the nature of the transformation she or he undergoes.

---

> Of course, even by 1946 clues were available in the theoretical reaches of quantum physics. In fact, then-modern technology, up to and including nuclear weapons and the fusion devices in the process of development, was largely based upon quantum mechanics, much of the work being done on the basis of “we know it works, but we don’t know how.” Given the impetus of the reality of wild card, psi powers were quickly given a quantum mechanical rationale; “action over distance” without apparent recourse to the strong, electroweak, or gravitic forces being a feature, for example, of the curious interconnectedness of particles that have interacted, postulated by Einstein, Podolsky, and Rosen in their famous “paradox,” and established with some finality by the Aspect experiment in France in 1982.…
>       … A fairly obvious instance of TK-based power is shape changing. The subject—in almost all cases subconsciously—rearranges her or his component atoms to produce a gross structure that differs considerably from the original: for example, Elephant Girl’s rather unsettling transformation into a flying Elephas maximus in apparent violation of the mass-energy conservation principle. At least in the case of Elephant Girl, this is explained by subconscious TK on the subatomic level; Ms. O’Reilly can apparently summon into being a cloud of virtual particles and maintain them in existence immensely longer than they would normally exist. (A discussion of virtual particles is, of course, likewise beyond the scope of this presentation. I refer the interested to articles concerning, for example, the particles that “carry” the strong interaction, and that for an infinitesimal instant violate the conservation principle.) As part of restoring herself to her original appearance, Ms. O’Reilly permits the virtual particles that made up the “phantom” mass to lapse into nonexistence.
>       It was Elephant Girl’s ability to fly in defiance of all known aeronautical principles that sparked the line of inquiry leading to the conclusions expressed in this paper. Simply put, Elephant Girl’s, Peregrine’s, and all known aces’ flight or levitation is simply a variation on TK. In this sense, the Great and Powerful Turtle is the archetypal flying ace, in that he acknowledgedly flies by means of his telekinetic ability. But no trick of physics would permit Elephant Girl’s ears or even Peregrine’s magnificent wings to uphold even a small human in flight, to say nothing of a full-grown Asiatic elephant. They, like the Turtle, fly through use of mind power alone.…
>       … Energy projections provide another thorny problem simply explained by—again—TK. Jumpin’ Jack Flash appears to project blasts of flame from the palms of his hands, and moreover can manipulate the fire he produces in remarkable ways. But this individual does not actually project the flame, in the sense that it is not emitted from his own body; in point of fact, it isn’t strictly speaking flame. His TK enables him to regulate the Brownian motion of the circumambient air. He creates a “hot spot” of highly excited particles approximately one micron from the flesh of his palm, and then uses TK to direct the resultant stream of incandescent gas.

Comment: This is an interesting read, but I don't think it answers the question.